# CSS Positioning With Navbar

Tags: css

In the image below it shows an **image** , **textbox** and a **css menu image**

My CSS menu is perfect. I finally got it the way I needed it. My problem is that I need the textbox in the center of the nav bar and then I need my image to the **left** of the textbox 
to be all the way to the left. I don’t know how to do that. I have tryed this:

```
<!-- Advsearch -->
    <li class='active'><a href='#Searching'><span>
     <form method="get" STYLE="FLOAT:CENTER;" action="/search" id="advsearch">
       <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
       </form>
```

And for the image I tried `float:left`

I made a jsfiddle for you to help me:

**Js Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/TxeVt/

[image]

Comment: There no such thing as `float: center;`

Comment: i have use float:center; before in project's and my older cousin who has been doing his for 3 years has used it also but refuses to help me -,-

Comment: Use it all you want.. but it does nothing. You're code in the Fiddle is pretty bad. Unclosed anchor tag, random `</img>` tag (which also does not exist), deprecated `<font>`, `<b>`, and `<i>` tags. You may want to first use valid code.

Comment: @scott http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

Comment: You mean http://w3fools.com -- w3schools site is a joke. it is inaccurate, flat out wrong, and often misleading. You shouldn't use it for reference. The font, b, and i tags were deprecated years ago.

Comment: @Scott is right. Please avoid using W3Schools for any serious web design/development work, especially when you're learning. As boring as this website may be, I'd recommend you use the W3C's site, http://www.w3c.org/ It has all the info you'd need.

Comment: Nah.. he can continue using it.. according to his profile link.. he'll "make you 7 html/css/php pages for $5"  -- You get what you pay for.

Comment: @Scott actually iv been doing this for a while just never payed attention to depricated code and stuff i should look into it to

Comment: Actually, the `<b>` and `<i>` elements are *not* deprecated. The `<i>` element is for text in an alternate voice, and the `<b>` element is for stylistically offset text. There is however, no such thing as float: center. There was almost everything else including float: positioned (spec now deprecated in favour of Exclusions), top, bottom,  top-corner, bottom-corner, and snap.

Comment: Actually , I don't exactly know what you need , but here , I write some code > http://jsfiddle.net/TxeVt/4/ , check it out .

Comment: @ Jase , I really want to see `float:center;` in the next version of CSS :D , and you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

correct `{ margin: 0 auto;}`  not `{ float:center }`

and you are using `float:center`, center is not element float element are available is left, right, none, inherit Ok dude

Comment: ok well they still arent being positioned correctly in my html even with this http://jsfiddle.net/TxeVt/ <~ jsfiddle with the code i alredy have i alredy have it like i need it just that i need the search centerd and the logo image to the left